# Twitch Status for IPB forum

Tags: javascript, twitch

I am looking for Twitch status toggle for my forum. I have a list with streamers and I want  green/red point for online/offline streams or just ONLINE or OFFLINE.  I found what I need but was unable to make it work. Every help will be welcome.

Here is the code I found:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYv3R/5/

Regards

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ltwitch').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
     $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+tnick+".json?callback=?", function(c) {
      if (c.stream == null) {
       span.html("Offline");
      } else {
       span.html("Online");
      }
     });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ltwitch" href="#" data-tnick="xxx">xxx</a> (<span>...</span>)
<a class="ltwitch" href="#" data-tnick="name1">name2</a> (<span>...</span>)
<a class="ltwitch" href="#" data-tnick="name2">name3</a> (<span>...</span>)
```

Comment: [Here's a full example you can take a look at](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-twitchtv-app-project-8824d61fe7a5#.p7006xh5l)

Comment: Anyone can help me ?